# Check a String for a Slash

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, windows

```
string testStr="thestringhasa\slash";

if(testStr.Contains("\"))
{
    //Code to process string with \
}
```

How do I properly test to see if a string contains a backslash, when I try the it statement if says a New Line in constant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other two answers are entirely correct, but no one bothered to explain why. The \ character has a special purpose in C# strings. It is the escape character, so to have a string that contains a slash, you have to use one of two methods.

1. Use the string literal symbol @. A string preceded by the @ symbol tells the C# compiler to treat the string as a literal and not escape anything.
2. Use the escape character to tell the C# compiler there is a special character that is actually part of the string.

So, the following strings are equivalent:

```
var temp1 = @"test\test";
var test2 = "test\\test";

test1 == test2; // Yields true
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use double slashes

```
string testStr=@"thestringhasa\slash";

if(testStr.Contains("\\"))
{
    //Code to process string with \
}
```

Comment: Also the testStr should contain escaped slash `\\\` for appropriate test. Or use string testStr=@"thestringhasa\slash";

Answer (score 5):

The backslash must be escaped. Try the following:

```
string testStr = @"thestringhasa\slash";

if (testStr.Contains("\\"))
{
    //Code to process string with \
}
```